# UIAlertController remove blurry layer

Tags: ios, swift, background-color, layer, uialertcontroller

With a custom UIAlertController, I am trying to set the background color to solid red. However, I am getting another blurry layer on top. How do I get rid of the blurry layer?

```
class CustomAlert: UIAlertController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.RED
    }
}

let popUpEmailVerification: CustomAlert = {
        let alert = CustomAlert(title: nil, message: "A verification email has been sent to your mailbox. Please open the link to finish verification.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    return alert
}()
```

[image]

Comment: Feels like you are missing things. Why is anything "blurry"? We need more context - both code and anything else - to really help.

Comment: I have set the background red, and it's red as you can see in the corners, but it also looks like there's another round cornered layer overlapping it. What I want is a solid red block. I have added the implementation code (please see edit). Nothing else is missing now.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct API to achieve the effect you want, as far as I'm aware.

However, you can do what you're describing by messing around with the undocumented view hierarchy of the alert, like so:

`let bgView = (alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first!)! as UIView`

and then set `bgView.backgroundColor = .red`. This is likely to bite you later.

Alternatively, you could use one of the many custom Alert libaries out here, [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView) is one that I've used with good success.